# How do I run my java application on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

My class contains the main method and my class name matches the name of the file but when I want to run it, it gives the options to run as "ant build" or "ant build...". Run as java application is not working for me. What could be wrong?

Comment: Could this be of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068440/eclipse-wont-compile-run-java-file

Comment: What error are you getting ?